# R convention for naming large numbers of contributors in R (/CRAN) package documentation?

Tags: r, cran

`ctb` is an R package role specifically [for authors who have made smaller contributions](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-1/RJournal_2012-1_Hornik~et~al.pdf#page=2) to an R package

What is best practice for handling *large numbers* of contributors?

#### Notes

- Some contributors who have made PRs to a package's github repository may not even display their real name (so contacting to obtain details could be somewhat burdensome if there are many).
- Some packages have 100+ contributors. For example, dplyr, which [currently has 182 contributors](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr).

Answer (score 0):

It may be appropriate to define a **Core Team** on your web site, then cite like:

```
@Manual{,
title = {Your contribution},
author = {Core Team},
year = {2019},
url = {Your web site},
}
```

See `citation()`.